# C++ abort has been called

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am doing multithreading in C++. I'm on Windows.
This is what I have:

```
int i;
    try {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        for (i = 0; i < threadscount; i++) {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(myvoid));
            std::cout << "started\n";
        }

        for (i = 0; i < threadscount; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
            std::cout << "joined\n";
        }
    }
    catch (...) {}
```

But when I set `threadscount` to 2000 threads I get:

> abort() has been called.

Why does this happen? Can I get a solution to fix this?

Comment: If you really want to know, run your code in a debugger; it should pause when abort is called. As SergeyA notes, though, 2000 threads is overkill.

Comment: 32 bits or 64 bits?  Each thread takes 2M memory for the stack.  2000 threads is 4G memory for stacks alone.  That won't fit in 2G of virtual memory in a 32-bit program.

Comment: @MartinBonner, good catch. Didn't think about it, haven't dealt with 32bit for ages...

Comment: What you want to do is to use a list of functions that you want to execute in parallel and make a few threads (maybe 4 for a dual core) and have them pop a function and execute it and then pop the next function. You will need to synchronize that list.

Comment: If you have 2000 threads, how do you expect the CPU cores to do anything else than swapping between the threads? For a four-core system it's at least 500 threads per core (remember that there are other processes and threads running too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that on windows the limitiation is stack space. You can increase the number of threads if you reduce the amount of stack space given to each.

reference here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773/

edit:

just knocked up this test program on my imac. managed to create 2047 threads before running out of resources. Your mileage may vary :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>


void myvoid()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}

void start_thread(std::vector<std::thread>& threads)
{
    try
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(myvoid));
        std::cout << "started " << threads.size() <<"\n";
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "failed to start at " << threads.size() + 1 << "\n";
        throw;
    }
}

auto main() -> int
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    try {
        for(;;)
            start_thread(threads);
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }

    for (auto& t : threads) {
        if (t.joinable()) {
            t.join();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
...
started 2042
started 2043
started 2044
started 2045
started 2046
started 2047
failed to start at 2048
$
```

Comment: Thank you for the point, but it's not worth it. Unfortunately, I can't upvote for user restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Because no one can expect to be able to launch 2000 threads. You computer does not have resources for this.

There is a simple solution to this - use a sane number of threads. Hint - anything above 50 is likely insane, unless you have a very special circumstances.

Comment: How is it possible? I can perfectly launch 2000 threads in Java or .NET (with the same translated method).

Comment: I am not familair with .NET and have very limited exposure to Java, but no system can handle 2000 real threads. It is possible that the threads you launch from there are not real kernel threads.

Comment: Well, so there isn't any solution?

Comment: I can launch at least 10000 threads on my machine with the OP's code.

Comment: @NathanOliver, your power is bigger than OPs :) Still insane.

Comment: Like I said - there is a solution. You can't for real have 2000 threads running, it is not going to give you any benefit. Use a sane number of threads.

Comment: Thanks for the point. I will calm down to run threads. Unfortunately, I can't upvote for user restrictions.

Comment: I have, in the past  created 5000 threads, (Vista 64).  No problem at all. No effect on normal operations.  Could not tell they were there.

Answer (score 0):

If the system runs out of resources while trying to create all those threads then this line will probably throw an exception:

```
        threads.push_back(std::thread(myvoid));
```

That will destroy the vector `threads`, which will then call `std::terminate()` because it destroys a `std::thread` that is joinable.

You can make the code safe by moving the declaration of `threads` before the `try` block, and then making sure you join (or detach) all the threads in the `catch` handler.

Comment: Thank you for the point. Can you do an example _to make sure I join (or detach) all the threads in the catch handler_?

Comment: You're already joining them in a loop, but that code won't run if an exception is thrown. You just need to make sure that loop (or a similar one) happens when an exception is thrown, to join the threads before they are destroyed.